# Calculating Rolling Weekly Spend in Hive using Window Functions

Tags: hadoop, hive, window-functions, partition

I need to develop a distribution of customer week long spend. Every time a customer makes a purchase, I want to know how much they've spent with us in the past week. I would like to do this with my Hive code.

My data set is somewhat similar to this:

Spend_Table

```
Cust_ID | Purch_Date | Purch_Amount  
1 | 1/1/19 | $10  
1 | 1/2/19 | $21  
1 | 1/3/19 | $30  
1 | 1/4/19 | $11  
1 | 1/5/19 | $21  
1 | 1/6/19 | $31  
1 | 1/7/19 | $41  
2 | 1/1/19 | $12  
2 | 1/2/19 | $22  
2 | 1/3/19 | $32  
2 | 1/5/19 | $42  
2 | 1/7/19 | $52  
2 | 1/9/19 | $62  
2 | 1/11/19 | $72
```

So far, I've tried code that looks similar to this:

```
Select Cust_ID, 
Purch_Date, 
Purch_Amount,
sum(Purch_Amount) over (partition by Cust_ID order by unix_timestamp(Purch_Date) range between 604800 and current row) as Rolling_Spend
from Spend_Table



Cust_ID | Purch_Date | Purch_Amount | Rolling_Spend  
1 | 1/1/19 | $10 | $10  
1 | 1/2/19 | $21 | $31  
1 | 1/3/19 | $30 | $61  
1 | 1/4/19 | $11 | $72  
1 | 1/5/19 | $21 | $93  
1 | 1/6/19 | $31 | $124  
1 | 1/7/19 | $41 | $165  
2 | 1/1/19 | $12 | $12  
2 | 1/2/19 | $22 | $34  
2 | 1/3/19 | $32 | $66  
2 | 1/5/19 | $42 | $108  
2 | 1/7/19 | $52 | $160  
2 | 1/9/19 | $62 | $188  
2 | 1/11/19 | $72 | $228
```

I believe the issue is with my range between, because it appears to be grabbing the preceding number of rows. I was expecting it to grab data within the preceding amount of seconds (604800 being 6 days in seconds).

Is what I'm trying to do feasible? I can't do the previous 6 rows, since not every customer makes a purchase every single day, like customer 2. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *, sum(some_value) OVER (
        PARTITION BY Cust_ID 
        ORDER BY CAST(Purch_Date AS timestamp) 
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 7 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     ) AS cummulativeSum FROM Spend_Table
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics

Comment: I tried running the code, but received the following error:
 ParseException line 13:129 cannot recognize input near 'INTERVAL' '7' 'DAYS' in windowframeboundary

I'm using Hue to run the Hive code

Comment: You need to cast date to timestamp

Comment: I have the cast as timestamp in there (double checked to make sure) but still received the same error message

Comment: Depends on what Hive version you're running? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-10911

Comment: @Achyuth and mazaneicha thank you both for the help. Wasn't sure which Hive version I was running, but I kept trying with the original query and was able to get it running by adding 
unix_timestamp(Purch_date,'MM-dd-yyyy'). Updated my original post with the solution

Answer (score 0):

Moving answer here from the question,

> I was able to get the original code to work by changing it to:
>
> ```
> Select Cust_ID, 
> Purch_Date, 
> Purch_Amount,
> sum(Purch_Amount) over (partition by Cust_ID order by unix_timestamp(Purch_Date, 'MM-dd-yyyy') range between 604800 and
> ```
>
> current row) as Rolling_Spend
> from Spend_Table
>
> The key was specifying the date format in the unix_timestamp formula